# Determine whether the target of a selector has been formatted as a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I've tried looking at other questions but none seem to work because they're testing whether the selected object is an HTML element rather than a jQuery-ui object.  In short, I'm looking for the following:

```
var slider = $("#slider").slider();
if(slider.????) // return true because jQuery created a slider
    alert("It's a slider!");
else
    alert("Not a slider.");
```

Comment: Are you wanting to check to see if an element was found that matched the selector? Or is it actually as your question states, and you want to check to see if the element was "formatted as a slider"?

Comment: ...if the latter, who knows? jQuery doesn't have a `.slider()` method, so it depends on that plugin. Is there a reason you'd think the plugin would fail?

Comment: Well, that code is pretty simplified.  I'm actually passing the selector from another function, and when it gets to the new function, I want to figure out what it is, so I know how to handle it.  My answer below solves the problem.  I should have thought of it earlier.

Comment: So you're actually asking about jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

```
slider.hasClass('ui-slider');
```

should do it.